# Deleting a child node stops other siblings from being deleted?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I'm trying to remove all the child nodes with class .FormErrorMessage from element #LoginFormErrorWrapper. These are XUL "description" elements if that makes a difference.

Using this code:

```
var Messages = document.getElementById('LoginFormErrorWrapper').getElementsByClassName("FormErrorMessage");
for (var i = 0; i < Messages.length; i++) {
   var node = Messages[i];
   document.getElementById('LoginFormErrorWrapper').removeChild(node); 
}
```

Only the first element is deleted. Messages contains all of the elements, but once the first child gets deleted, the loop stops. If I comment out the removeChild line and alert the node, it alerts all of the nodes. Why does it stop looping after the first child is deleted? The parent still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a **live** NodeList. So while you remove an element from the DOM it is also removed from the NodeList, causing various side effects.

You can avoid them by converting the NodeList to an Array

```
var Messages = [].slice.call(document.getElementById('LoginFormErrorWrapper').getElementsByClassName("FormErrorMessage"));
```